# How To Select Manager Name From This Stored Procedure?

Tags: join, sql-server-2005

I am trying to get an employee manager's first and last name IF the employee has a manager ( Some employee's do not ex CEO etc ). Currently it returns the employee name for manager and if there is no ManagerID in contact it wont return any values

Here is my general table structure for the tables I'm trying to access:

Employee

```
EmpID
EmployeeNumber
StartDate
isManager
Status ( full time / part time )
ContactID
```

Contact

```
ContactID
Fname
Lname
ManagerID
```

Department

```
DeptID
Name
```

DeptHistory

```
DeptHistID
DeptID
EmpID
PosTitle
StartDate
EndDate
ModifiedDate
```

And here is the query I have been manipulating:

```
SELECT 
   dh.StartDate, dh.PositionTitle, d.Name,
   e.EmployeeNumber, e.Classification, e.Status,
   c1.FirstName, c1.LastName, c1.SIN,
   c1.DateOfBirth, c1.PhoneNumber, c1.EmailAddress, c1.AddressLine1,
   c1.AddressLine2, c1.PostalCode, c1.City, c1.Province,
   (c2.FirstName+ ' ' + c2.LastName) AS Manager
FROM 
    Person.Contact c1
JOIN 
    HumanResources.Employee e ON c1.ContactID = e.ContactID
JOIN 
    HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory dh ON e.EmpID = dh.EmpID
JOIN 
    HumanResources.Department d ON dh.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
JOIN 
    Person.Contact c2 ON c2.ManagerID = e.EmpID
WHERE 
    e.EmpID = @empID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `JOIN`, so the query would look like this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person.Contact c2 ON c2.ManagerID = e.EmpID
```

`OUTER` word is optional so you can use just `LEFT JOIN`.

See [Using Left Outer Joins](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.90).aspx#Anchor_0) on Microsoft's TechNet.

Comment: This fixes it not returning any values which is great, half the problem done. I just read on different types of joins and learned exactly what this is doing. 

There still remains a problem though , even with this in here if I insert a new employee ( EmpID = 2 ) and I set the managerID to be (1, the EmpID of the first employee) and execute this query passing EmpID 2, itll return null , when it shuold return the first employees full name

Comment: I am still fiddling , I think I need to add a condition in the WHERE clause

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Does it work as expected if you remove the join of `Person.Contact` table?

Comment: No , as the majority of the data I am trying to pull is from this table. I'll explain in laymans to help illustrate the problem:  The Person.Contact table is filled with personal information about an emp ie Fname, Lname, Phone, Email, Etc.. my goal is to enter an employee number and it return me that employee's personal information , along with his/her managers name.

Comment: OK, so first step is to make it work without managers, that means without `Person.Contact` table join. Even after that query is working as expected I would discuss how to add manager information.

Comment: so say employee 1 name is John Doe and is a manager of employee 2 Sally Smith, when I search using sally's ID (2) I want it to return me her information , along with John Doe as her manager name

Comment: Currently it does work and pulls all the information I am looking for. I took it slow and step by step as well as planned on paper to get to this point. Now I am trying to  get the manager information out of it

Comment: I see. So I don't understand why did you answer "no" to my question if it works without the `Person.Contact` join. But in that case it should work with the `LEFT JOIN`. Let me check it again.

Comment: I was just confused momentarily my apologies. I beleive I see what is wrong , once I pass the procedure emp ID 2 for Sally's info, the join will return nothing for that value as ManagerID for Sally would be 1

Comment: In your question, you wrote that it doesn't work only for ManagerID which doesn't exist (I guess it's `null`).

Comment: Yes I set in the table to default null, you helped solve the error of it not returning anything by using Left Join if there isnt a managerID for that specific employee in the contact table

Comment: So what's the exact problem? I'm lost a bit now.

Comment: the problem is , when i run this stored procedure passing 2 for employee id ( Sallys ) , it would return all her personal info etc but have the manager field null when it shuold return John Doe as the manager name. Sally's ManagerID is 1 which refers to John Doe (ManagerID is actually an EmpID from employee table, the value is grabbed from a combobox in vb.net but that is irrelavent)